# Apache Http HttpAsyncClient NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache, noclassdeffounderror, asynchttpclient

I'm using [apache http async client library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/examples.html) in order to create async http requests.

added to my maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code is using `HttpAsyncClientBuilder` in order to build the client. In runtime I get an exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/util/PublicSuffixMatcherLoader
```

It seems that this jar is missing some dependencies.
Any advice?